# Add Control Value before another Control value in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, flowlayoutpanel

I have a "FlowLayoutPanel" and want to add series of "UserControl" to it:

> mainPanel.Controls.Add(fx);

Every new usercontrol added after old one, I want to add new usercontrol before the previous usercontrol that was added how could I do this? I didn't find any functionality like `mainPanel.Controls.AddAt(...)` or `mainPanel.Controls.Add(index i, Control c)` or `mainPanel.Controls.sort(...)` or ... .

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the [SetChildIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex.aspx) method. Something like (maybe you need to fiddle with the indecies):

```
var prevIndex = mainPanel.Controls.IndexOf(previouslyAdded)
mainPanel.Controls.Add(fx);
mainPanel.Controls.SetChildIndex(fx, prevIndex);
```

Answer (score 4):

by the sounds of it you want to change the flowdirection attribute  so that newest controls added are added to the top

```
flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.BottomUp;
```

or you could

```
 Label label1 = new Label();
 flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label1);
 label1.BringToFront();
```

Comment: If I change flow direction  my problem don't solve, it just add from right to left instead of left to right, but still add after old userControl

Comment: But if it is adding from left to right does it not layout like oldest control to far right newest control to far left?

Comment: Sorry I had my second option backwards...  I had SendToBack  should have been BringToFront

Answer (score 0):

Correcting myself: `myPanel.Controls.AddAt(index, myControl)`

Comment: No, there is not such method, we just have Add().

Comment: Nevermind, I was thinking about ASP.NET WebForms. I think you're dealing with WPF, right?  If so, please retag.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will add a control in alphabetical order.

```
                    FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel = ...; // this is the flow panel
                    Control control = ...; // this is the control you want to add in alpha order.

                    flowLayoutPanel.SuspendLayout();
                    flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(control);

                    // sort it alphabetically
                    for (int i = 0; i < flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var otherControl = flowLayoutPanel.Controls[i];
                        if (otherControl != null && string.Compare(otherControl.Name, control.Name) > 0)
                        {
                            flowLayoutPanel.Controls.SetChildIndex(control, i);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    flowLayoutPanel.ResumeLayout();
```